# Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath' - matplotlib-cpp setup on VisualStudio2019

Tags: c++, numpy, matplotlib, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to install matplotlib-cpp in my C++ environment (Visual Studio 2019) in order to do data visualization. I configured all the "include" files, "additional include" files and the "library" file to connect Visual Studio with my Python directory.

[image: Include directories]

[image: Library directories]

I try to plot an example figure:

```cpp
#include "matplotlibcpp.h"

namespace plt = matplotlibcpp;

int main()
{
    plt::plot({1, 2, 3});
    plt::show();
}
```

But I get an error:

```
IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.9 from "C:\Users\xxxxx\source\repos\ProjectName\x64\Debug\ProjectName.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.21.2"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

- Python version: 3.9.0
- NumPy version : 1.21.2

I have already upgrade/reinstalled NumPy and Matplotlib with `pip`.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to link the x86 library to your x64 project.

Comment: @CoryKramer if I set up the project in x86, Python is not recognized anymore. I think that matplotlib-cpp has no x64 version.

Comment: It looks like they have CMake integration. If you set up your project to use CMake then it would be as simple as `find_package(matplotlib_cpp REQUIRED)`